# Why such a difference in IL between IF and the conditional operator?

Tags: c#, il

C# has a [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and IF statements and I suspected that the conditional operator would be just syntactic sugar. So at compile time it would have a the same as an IF operation.

However they do not (see below), they do have different IL. Trying to wrap my head around it and the assumption I have is that this is a performance optimisation that the conditional operator gets because it's limited scope.

Would like to know if my assumption is correct or not and maybe if there is more to this?

Also in the IF's IL there is some checks (L_000c, L_000d, L_000f) around int values which I can't figure out the meaning. This is what has lead me to think this is a more robust solution, at the cost of performance because of IF greater scope.

---

Code for IF

```
var result = "";
if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
{
    result = "Yes";
}
else
{
    result = "No";
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Code for conditional operator (I realise differences, but no matter how I change it - assign to variable etc... it makes very little difference)

```
Console.WriteLine("Is the OS x64? {0}", Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? "Yes" : "No");
```

IL for IF

```
L_0001: ldstr ""
L_0006: stloc.0 
L_0007: call bool [mscorlib]System.Environment::get_Is64BitOperatingSystem()
L_000c: ldc.i4.0 
L_000d: ceq 
L_000f: stloc.2 
L_0010: ldloc.2 
L_0011: brtrue.s L_001d
L_0013: nop 
L_0014: ldstr "Yes"
L_0019: stloc.0 
L_001a: nop 
L_001b: br.s L_0025
L_001d: nop 
L_001e: ldstr "No"
L_0023: stloc.0 
L_0024: nop 
L_0025: ldloc.0 
L_0026: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

IL for Conditional

```
L_002c: ldstr "Is the OS x64? {0}"
L_0031: call bool [mscorlib]System.Environment::get_Is64BitOperatingSystem()
L_0036: brtrue.s L_003f
L_0038: ldstr "No"
L_003d: br.s L_0044
L_003f: ldstr "Yes"
L_0044: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string, object)
```

Comment: Just to be sure: Are you compiling in Release mode (The NOPs make it look like Debug Mode at first glance)? In Debug mode, the compiler doesn't do all optimizations to make debugging easier.

Comment: Is this debug or release mode? The interspersed `nop`s are used for break points, as far as I know.

Comment: Haha, 3 comments on the same thing within 7 seconds :P

Comment: That is a debug build; all bets are off until you look at a release build.

Comment: Your code isn't the same as well, `Console.WriteLine(String)` vs `Console.WriteLine(String, String)`.

Comment: All correct, it was in debug mode and in release mode it is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**if**

```
IL_0000:  call       bool [mscorlib]System.Environment::get_Is64BitOperatingSystem()
IL_0005:  brfalse.s  IL_000f
IL_0007:  ldstr      "Yes"
IL_000c:  stloc.0                  // <------ Difference 1
IL_000d:  br.s       IL_0015
IL_000f:  ldstr      "No"
IL_0014:  stloc.0
IL_0015:  ldloc.0
IL_0016:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

**? (ternary operator**)

```
IL_001b:  call       bool [mscorlib]System.Environment::get_Is64BitOperatingSystem()
IL_0020:  brtrue.s   IL_0029
IL_0022:  ldstr      "No"          // <------ Difference 2
IL_0027:  br.s       IL_002e
IL_0029:  ldstr      "Yes"
IL_002e:  stloc.0
IL_002f:  ldloc.0
IL_0030:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

(nearly)same code for both in release mode. The `if` adds a second `stdloc.0` that isn't optimized away by the compiler. And the other difference is that the `true` and `false` are inverted.

(so I learn that I should ALWAYS fire up WinMerge!)

And THIS would be an interesting question. Why are they inverted? Is there any logic?

Comment: Yip, well spotted. The issue is the release mode vs. debug mode.

Comment: You say "the only difference", but of course, in the `?` case, `001b`-`0029` are computing the *value* of the conditional expression, and then it's finally assigned to a variable at `002e`, whereas under the if statement, there are two possible assignments (`000c` and `0014`), which of course could be to unrelated variables, and the `if` statement doesn't *have* a value.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Right. Corrected. This teach me that WinMerge is the best friend of programmer :-)